# What is SemanticScreenReader.Announce(CalculateBtn.Text);

Tags: .net, maui

I can delete this in my code if VS has not bugged and my app still works. I want to understand what this does but i can't because i could not find an explanation.

I looked it up on the internet could not find a good answer.

Thankyou in advance.

Answer (score 5):

It's in the docs under accessibility, see the link here: https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/maui/fundamentals/accessibility?view=net-maui-7.0#semantic-screen-reader

> .NET MAUI provides the ISemanticScreenReader interface, with which you can instruct a screen reader to announce text to the user. The interface is exposed through the `SemanticScreenReader.Default` property, and is available in the `Microsoft.Maui.Accessibility` namespace.

So in short, this helps make you app more accessible. The `SemanticScreenReader` can be used to read something out loud to someone who is visually impaired.

In your case, you try to use `CalculateBtn`. I can imagine that this button maybe gets a new text assigned when a math sum is calculated and the result is put in the text of the button. At that point it would make sense to have a call to the `SemanticScreenReader.Announce()` to let someone, who cannot see the updated value visually, that a new value is shown on the button.

This example has a lot of assumptions about what you are doing and how, but it's just to give you some idea.

Answer (score 0):

This is used for reading out loud (announce) the text (CalculateBtn.Text) when a screen reader is activated.